# Showing that $x^me^{-ax}$ is bounded

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Let $a>0$, $m\geq 0$ and let $f:[0,\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be defined as $f(x)=x^me^{-ax}$. It should be true that this function is bounded, because near $0$ both terms are bounded, and far from $0$ the term $e^{-ax}$ decreases more rapidly than the term $x^m$ increases. What is a nice way to show this rigorously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since
$$
\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)=0,
$$
there exists $r>0$ such that 
$$
f(x) \le 1 \quad \forall x \ge r.
$$
Thus for every $x \ge 0$ we have
$$
f(x) \le \max\{\max_{0 \le x \le r}f(x),1\}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

We can bound instead $g(x) = f(\frac{m}{a}x) \left (\frac{a}{m} \right )^m$

Then we get

\begin{align}
g(x) = \frac{x^m}{ e^m} &\leq \\
\frac{x^m}{\left (e^x \right )^m} &\leq\\
x^m \frac{1}{(\sum _{k\geq 0} \frac{x^k}{k!} )^m }&\leq\\
x^m \frac{1}{(x+1)^m}&\leq 1
\end{align}